# Error load Infinite Scroll ( @ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) infitniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll; ) ionic 5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic, ionic4

Tengo el siguiente error en`load Infinite Scroll`

> ERROR in src/app/pages/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll.page.ts:11:4 - error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
>    11   @ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) infitniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;
>          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:7888:47
>        7888     (selector: Type | Function | string, opts: {
>                                                          ~~~~~~~
>        7889         read?: any;
>             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>        7890         static: boolean;
>             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>        7891     }): any;
>             ~~~~~
>       An argument for 'opts' was not provided.

Comment: Esta parece ser una posible solucion

@ViewChild( IonInfiniteScroll , {static: false} ) infitniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;

Answer (score 1):

Agregue , `{static: false}` a la sentencia y funciono.

```
@ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll, {static: false}) infitniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;
```